# ElasticSearch must not (must (A and A and C) or (D and E and F)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm trying to write a request :
must not ((must (A and A and C) or (D and E and F))

here what i have for must not ((must (A and A and C)) but can't add new "must"

```
GET     file_index_1/_search
{    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must_not" : {
                      "bool": {
                            "must": [{"match": {"field1": "A"}},
                                     {"match": {"field2":"B"}},
                                     {"match":{"field3":"C"}}]
                      }
            }              
          }                        
      } 
}
```

Any help will be appreciated :)
thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a combination of `bool/must/should/must_not` clause, to achieve your required condition

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "field1": "A"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "field2": "B"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "field3": "C"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "field1": "D"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "field2": "E"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "field3": "F"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @sysley please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?